# Redshift sum window function over previous 1 and next 1 numerical values of a numeric column, even if these values do not exist

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a table on Redshift like below:

Dimension 1 , Dimension 2, Built_year (numeric column), Units_sold

I need to sum the measure for built_year-1, current built_year, built_year+1 for every combination of Dimension 1, Dimension 2.

The problem is that by using SUM() window function I accomplish to sum the measure of the previous and the next row of built_year variable, and in many cases the previous and next lines are not built_year-1, built_year+1, but built_year-3, built_year+2 etc. So Not all built_year values are found in sequence in the variable built_year.

My code is:

```
with sold_per_cluster as 
(
select t2.dimension1 AS make,
       t3.dimension2 AS model, 
       t1.built_year AS built_year,
       count(distinct t1.id) as units_sold
       
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 ON t2.code = t1.code   -- #
left join table3 t3  ON t3.id = t1.type_id   -- #
where 1 
and t1.paid_bool = 1
and t1.paid_datetime >= getdate() - interval '2 year'
group by 1,2,3
order by 1,2,3 asc


)

select make, model,built_year, 
       sum(units_sold) over (partition by make,model order by built_year
                            rows between 1 preceding and 1 following) as units_sold
from sold_per_cluster
group by 1,2,3, units_sold
```

It there a way on Redshift to sum over the numeric_value +1, -1 of the built_year  even if it does not exist?

Comment: It is more painful than it should be, but you can use a CTE with `row_number()` to generate numbers.

Comment: You mean to create all possible combinations of make, model, built_year, by adding all  intermediate missing years, and for rows in which built_year is NOT existend in the db, cars_sold=0, correct? What the other commenter to this post also suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'No' is the answer to your question.

You need to UNION ALL all combination of dimension and year with units_sold of 0 to your data and then SUM() units sold to add the zeroes to the current data set.  (The SUM() can be done in your top select as window functions run after group by and aggregate functions.)  This way you have zeroes for the previous and next year for the window function to operate on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also thought of doing that , but I hoped there was a more elegant solution to my problem.